# Loop Statement does not go past 2nd item

Tags: c#

I am still a beginner developer - so forgive me if I get this question horibly wrong, but I have a class that builds a string based on the properties of another public struct.  This used to work fine when the struct was named, but I wanted to allow this class to do the same with any kind of struct so I changed to using objects.  This is the methoed I use to loop through the properties and construct the string - this is in a public class called constructors which I then call (without creating an instance of constructors) from the rest of my code.

```
    public string MyConstructor(object TheObject)
    {
        string S = "";

        Type t = TheObject.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] PI = t.GetProperties();

        Constructors Cons = new Constructors();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in PI)
        {
            S = MyConstructor(S, info, info.GetValue(TheObject, null););
        }

        return S;
    }
```

My problem is that it does not want to get out of the foreach loop.  When I replaced it with

```
        for (int i = 0; i < PI.Count(); i++)
        {
            S = MyConstructor(S, PI[i], PI[i].GetValue(TheObject, null));
        }
```

and ran it through the debugger -> after each loop i goes 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1... MyConstructor has 2 overloads... the one above and another with (string, PropertyInfo, object).  But even if I change the name of the second method to MyPropertyConstructor the same happens.  At the moment the code is called from a form with no Threads so there isn't any other threads that could in my mind interfere.  Also for loop 0 and 1 the method returns empty strings "".  So how do I get out of this loop?

Here is the the rest of the code

```
    public static string MyConstructor(string CompiledString, PropertyInfo PropertyToAdd, object ThisValue)
    {
        string s = "";
        //object ThisValue = PropertyToAdd.GetValue(PropertyToAdd, null);

        //See if there is something to work with
        if(PropertyToAdd != null)
        {
            //Remove items which has been set not to record
            if (PropertyToAdd.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DontRecord), true).Length > 0)
            {
                if(((DontRecord)PropertyToAdd.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DontRecord), true)[0]).Record)
                {
                    return CompiledString;
                }
            }

            //see if it is the first time using the compile string
            if (CompiledString != "")
            {
                s += ";";
            }

            //For Testing
            int testint = 0;

            //only record items that where default value is different to their value
            Object[] Attr = PropertyToAdd.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true);

            //see if there is a default value set
            if (Attr.Length > 0)
            {
                //Get Constructorname value
                Object[] constructorname = PropertyToAdd.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ConstructorName), true);

                if (constructorname.Length > 0)
                {
                    s += ((ConstructorName)constructorname[0]).Name.ToString() + "=";



                    //If value is a string
                    if (PropertyToAdd.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString(((DefaultValueAttribute)Attr[0]).Value) != (string)ThisValue) { s += ThisValue; } else { s = ""; }
                    }

                    //Incase value is an int
                    else if (PropertyToAdd.PropertyType == typeof(int) && int.TryParse(ThisValue.ToString(), out testint))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(((DefaultValueAttribute)Attr[0]).Value) != (int)ThisValue) { s += Convert.ToString((int)ThisValue); } else { s = ""; }
                    }

                    //Incase value is a bool
                    else if (PropertyToAdd.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(((DefaultValueAttribute)Attr[0]).Value) != (bool)ThisValue)
                        {
                            if ((bool)ThisValue) { s += "True"; } else { s += "False"; }
                        }
                        else { s = ""; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s = "";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //There is no ConstructorName so therefore cannot create
                    return CompiledString;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return CompiledString;
            }
        }

        return CompiledString += s;
    }

}
```

Here is a part of the type of objects passed initially to MyConstructor the public struct example

public struct ODBCDataString
    {
        #region Variables
            #region General Variables
                static string _connection = "";
                static string _saveString = "";
                static string _unsaveString = "";
            #endregion General Variables

```
        #region Security Variables
            static string _userID = "";
            static string _password = "";
        #endregion Security Variables

        #region Source Variables
            static string _dsn = "";
            static string _driver = "";
        #endregion Source Variables
    #endregion Variables

    #region Properties
        #region General
            [Browsable(false)]
            public string ConnectionString { get { return _connection; } set { _connection = value; } }

            [Browsable(false)]
            public string SaveString 
            {
                get 
                {
                    Constructors Cons = new Constructors();
                    string MyS = Cons.MyConstructor((object)this);
                    return MyS; 
                } 
            } 

            [Browsable(false)]
            public string UnsaveString 
            { 
                get 
                {
                    Constructors Cons = new Constructors();
                    string MyS = Cons.MyConstructor((object)this);
                    //string MyS = Constructors.MyConstructor((object)this);
                    if (_password != "")
                    {
                        MyS += ";Password=" + _password;
                    }

                    return MyS; 
                } 
            }
        #endregion General

        #region Source
            [DisplayName("DSN")]
            [Description("The DSN to use when connecting to the Data Source")]
            [DefaultValue("")]
            [Category("Source")]
            [ConstructorName("Dsn")]
            public string DSN { get { return _dsn; } set { _dsn = value; } }
```

... This is basically just a brief overview of the type of structs / objects that is passed

Comment: What is the value of PI.Count? And what are you expectiong?

Comment: Can you add what the other overload of `MyConstructor` does?

Comment: Sounds like there may be some infinite recursion going on...  Let's see the other `MyConstructor()`, I'm wondering if it doesn't call back to this one...

Comment: PI Count in this case is 6... for another struct it is more than 10, not sure how many though... basically I am trying to build different connection strings on the fly... it work fine when it only used SQL Connections (i.e. each property has a Attribute that lets my method know if it should be included or not)... really not that complicated until I got to this problem, and struggled the whole morning to solve

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see if you are caught in infinite recursion?

Comment: Surely he'd get a stack overflow if that was the case?

Comment: Can you show us the code for "TheObject" you're sending?

Comment: I Did step through and everything goes fine for the first 2 properties... i.e. in the for(int i = 0... case the first property returns "" (from second last return)... then i becomes one and returns the same [which is both correct], but then i becomes 0 again

Comment: Can you give definitions of `DontRecord` and `ConstructorName`?

Comment: ConstructorName is an Attribute which is just a string... this is where I define the name that should go in the string together with the Value [ConstructorName = Value].  the public class only have publci string{get{return name;}} in it with a constructor... Don't record is also attribute but with a bool instead of string.  If it is true then it should also not be included (for instance password details will by "DontRecord")

Comment: What is the type of `TheObject` that you are passing to the method when the error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs on the foreach loop... therefore the object is PI[i].GetValue(TheObject, null)); =>  Therefore the object is the Value (could be string, bool, etc) of the property of an object (which is a public struct -> if that maks sense Ivan?

Comment: If you could brief out what you are actually trying to achieve here, it would help greatly.

Comment: OK, but when you invoke `MyConstructor(object TheObject)` from somewhere in your app, what is the actual type and definition of the object that you are passing to this method? You say it's a public struct, can you post it's definition? I'm trying to recreate this situation on my machine.

Comment: Ivan - I have posted an example above now... but it is basically just a struct with properties... strings/bools/ints etc

Comment: Ps... as you can see the first three properties of each class should return an empty string... it is whithin the second one here that the loop gets reset.  although if I work with the debuger... the first property return empty string, when it returns i = 0.  Then i moves to 1 and second property is calculate - when that returns i = 0... i.e. somwhere when the property is "calculating i is reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry for wasting time here, but I found the problem.  It is as HOBO suggested.  one of my properties also called the same method (actually it was the second property of the exact class I set as the example above.  I commented that one out and code was working.  After an entire day spent - I feel like an idiot and wasted all you guys' time... THANK You SO SO Much for all your help :)  I almost gave up on developing all together :)

Comment: ps.  I thought the code will not get there to be honnest becasue of the Attribute ConstructorName that is not set... So Am I right in thinking that if you just want to know all the attributes of a property the value will also be returned with the rest of the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        string result = ObjToString<Test1>(t1);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string ObjToString<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("passed in parameter is null");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Type t = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            sb.Append(property.Name);
            sb.Append(",");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public struct Test1
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
}
```